# Reading selected text into a Python function without altering the clipboard, not even altering the multi-clipboard

Tags: python, windows, clipboard, copy-paste

I want to select some text with the mouse or keyboard, alter it using a Python function (e.g. replace a word with a different word), and then paste the altered text. I want to do this without changing what’s on the clipboard. I am not content to preserve only what is on the first slot of the clipboard; I want to preserve what is on every slot of the clipboard, or at least the first e.g. 50 slots. My question is how to do that?

I’m interested in doing this on Windows with Python.

Background: Windows recently introduced a native multi-clipboard (i.e. a clipboard with multiple slots) which can be accessed by pressing Windows-v ([see here](https://www.howtogeek.com/351978/using-windows-10s-new-clipboard-history-and-cloud-sync/)), and there also are third-party apps such as Copyq and Ditto which provide a multi-clipboard. When you copy something onto the Windows multi-clipboard, the thing you copied gets put on the first slot and everything else gets shifted down by one slot. A solution that uses the Windows multi-clipboard rather than a third-party application would be preferable but not essential. Pyperclip is a popular tool for reading text into Python functions from the clipboard and passing text back to the clipboard from Python functions. However, Pyperclip seems to only be able to interact with the first slot on the clipboard.

My current approach: 1) store the previous contents of the clipboard in a temporary variable, 2) copy the selected text into the clipboard, 3) pass the copied selected text into a Python function via Pyperclip, 4) alter the text using the Python function, 5) put the altered text back onto the clipboard using Pyperclip, 5) paste the altered text, 6) and finally put the original clipboard content back on the clipboard (using the temporary variable). But this approach is not good enough because it changes what is on the higher slots of the clipboard e.g. the second slot. In particular, it adds things to the clipboard thus shifting everything else down.

Is there a way to programmatically delete the extraneous content from the multi-clipboard once I am done with it? For example, once I pass the selected text from the clipboard into the Python function (where it will be manipulated), I would want to use the Python function to remove the selected text from the clipboard since it is no longer needed there. (I know you can delete text from the clipboard using the GUI, but I want to do so by using a Python function.) Alternatively, if there is a way to read selected text into a Python function (and paste it back out) without ever putting it on any slot of the multi-clipboard that would work too.

Thanks